# jquery- $(window).ready vs $(document).ready

Tags: jquery, document-ready

What is the difference between **$(window).ready** and **$(document).ready** in jquery. Both variants works.

Comment: This is not duplicate. I ask about $(window).ready  (not about window.onload)

Comment: `ready()` is not meant to be applied to `window`. Issuing `$(window).ready()` will not lead to anything good.

Comment: Maybe for now. Maybe in the specific version of jQuery you're using. There are no guarantees.